# Yield Prolog adaptation for Smalltalk

Tags: prolog, smalltalk, yield

How can I adapt the method described in http://yieldprolog.sourceforge.net to Pharo Smalltalk ?

Are there analogous to the yield and generator functions exist in Smalltalk ?

For start, how should I rewrite code from [Tutorial1](http://yieldprolog.sourceforge.net/tutorial1.html) with message passing:

- Generator function using yield:

`class UnifyingVariable:
    def __init__(self):
        self._isBound = False
    def unify(self, arg):
        if not self._isBound:
            self._value = arg
            self._isBound = True
            yield False
            # Remove the binding.
            self._isBound = False
        elif self._value == arg:
            yield False`

`def personWithUnify(Person):
    for l1 in Person.unify("Chelsea"):
        yield False
    for l1 in Person.unify("Hillary"):
        yield False
    for l1 in Person.unify("Bill"):
        yield False`

`def main():
    print("Names using UnifyingVariable:")
    Person = UnifyingVariable()
    for l1 in personWithUnify(Person):
        print(Person._value)`

Is it possible use single thread realisation, avoiding multithreading causes lot of complexity ?

Comment: This is an interesting topic, but to make it on-topic for SO you should at least provide an example showing the code you would like to translate to Smalltalk.

Comment: I remember a very old version of Smalltalk (I think it was in Smalltalk/V) where there was a Prolog compiler, and you could define in a class that it should use it to compile its methods.

Comment: @CarlosE.Ferro If I recall it correctly there was a Prolog inside Squeak too.

Answer (score 4):

Squeak Smalltalk has a `Generator` class with a `yield:` method (and if Pharo didn't remove it then it should still be there).

In Smalltalk, `yield` is not a keyword as in other languages, but implemented in Smalltalk itself. It uses a single thread with co-routines (manipulating the execution context).

Here's the first example from YieldProlog:

```
personWithReturnValue := Generator on: [ :g |
    g yield: 'Chelsea'.
    g yield: 'Hillary'.
    g yield: 'Bill' ].

Transcript cr; show: 'Names using a return value:'.
personWithReturnValue do: [ :p |
    Transcript cr; show: p ].
```

As long as the Generator is *side-effect free*, it can be used exactly as in other languages.

*However*, YieldProlog relies on side-effects when unifying its variables. The difference is that in Squeak the code up to the next `yield:` is executed immediately. That is, when creating the Generator, all the code up to the first `yield:` gets executed. On the first `next` call it executes all the code up to the second `yield:`, but answers the value of the first yield. And so on. This is so the Generator can detect when to stop executing (because it is a subclass of `Stream` and needs to support its `atEnd` interface).

This means that you would have to put the side-effects *after* the yield. E.g. for the second YieldProlog example this works:

```
Object subclass: #SimpleVariable
    instanceVariableNames: '_value'
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'YieldProlog'.

SimpleVariable createInstVarAccessors.

personWithSimpleVariable := [ :person |
    Generator on: [ :g |
        g yield: false.
        person _value: 'Chelsea'.

        g yield: false. 
        person _value: 'Hillary'.

        g yield: false.
        person _value: 'Bill' ] ].

Transcript cr; show: 'Names using a SimpleVariable:'.
p := SimpleVariable new.
(personWithSimpleVariable value: p) do: [ :l1 |
    Transcript cr; show: p _value ].
```

but in general this makes it hard to implement YieldProlog properly. Now, since `Generator` is implemented in Smalltalk, it's relatively easy to fix this, too. See the changeset posted at http://forum.world.st/Generators-td4941886.html

With that change, the UnifyingVariable example works:

```
Object subclass: #UnifyingVariable
    instanceVariableNames: '_value _isBound'
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'YieldProlog'.

UnifyingVariable createInstVarAccessors.

UnifyingVariable compile: 'unify: arg
    ^Generator on: [ :g |
        _isBound = true
            ifFalse: [ 
                _value := arg.
                _isBound := true.
                g yield: false.
                "Remove the binding".
                _isBound := false ]
            ifTrue: [
                _value = arg
                    ifTrue: [ g yield: false ] ] ]'.

personWithUnify := [ :person |
    Generator on: [:g |
        (person unify: 'Chelsea') do: [ :l1 |
            g yield: false ].
        (person unify: 'Hillary') do: [ :l1 |
            g yield: false ].
        (person unify: 'Bill') do: [ :l1 |
            g yield: false ] ] ].

Transcript cr; show: 'Names using a UnifyingVariable:'.
person := UnifyingVariable new.
(personWithUnify value: person) do: [ :l1 |
    Transcript cr; show: person _value ].

Transcript cr; show: 'Use unify to check a person:'.
person := UnifyingVariable new.
(person unify: 'Hillary') do: [ :l1 |
    (personWithUnify value: person) do: [ :l2 |
        Transcript cr; show: 'Hillary is a person.' ] ].
(person unify: 'Buddy') do: [ :l1 |
    (personWithUnify value: person) do: [ :l2 |
        "This won't print."
        Transcript cr; show: 'Buddy is a person.' ] ].
```

All this being said, I doubt that this YieldProlog implementation is as efficient as the actual Prolog for Squeak. You should have a look at that: http://www.zogotounga.net/comp/squeak/prolog.htm

Comment: Thanks Bert! I've checked and the `Generator` class is still in Pharo.